# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType., how to solve this problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-compose, mapping

I'm trying to install Jenkins in Ubuntu, and I don't known how to solve this problem. I attach a photo of the error.

Thanks! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjJYP.png)

Comment: Indent jenkins: - the yaml seems to be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 is syntax error. Please check with other example:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```